# How to exclude Pod Warnings with SwiftLint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftlint

Xcode shows Warnings for some of my Pod Files, especially warnings about deprecated variables.

I already have a .swiftlint.yml file and it is in the same folder as my Pods folder.

This is what my file looks like:

```
excluded:
   - Pods
   - Localization
line_length: 200
type_body_length:
   - 300 # warning
   - 400 # error
file_length:
warning: 500
error: 1200
function_body_length:
warning: 50
error: 100
```

I don't understand why it still shows these warnings when I exclude them.

Comment: Those are, probably, not SwiftLint warnings. And for Pod warning you can always try [`inhibit_all_warnings!`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#inhibit_all_warnings_bang).

Comment: @user28434 thank you, that worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Following will work to ignore the Pod files.

```
excluded: 
  - Pods
```

You just need to Make sure that your .swiftlint.yml file must be on the root path of project.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
platform :ios

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

# ignore warnings from a specific pod
pod 'SwiftLint', :inhibit_warnings => true
```